# Pandas read excel with Chinese filename

Tags: python, unicode, pandas, character-encoding

I am trying to load as a pandas dataframe a file that has Chinese characters in its name.

I've tried:

```
df=pd.read_excel("url/某物2008.xls")
```

and

```
import sys
df=pd.read_excel("url/某物2008.xls", encoding=sys.getfilesystemencoding())
```

But the response is something like: "no such file or directory "url/\xa1\xa92008.xls"

I've also tried changing the names of the files using os.rename, but the filenames aren't even read properly (asking python to just print the filenames yields only question marks or squares).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df=pd.read_excel(u"url/某物2008.xls", encoding=sys.getfilesystemencoding())
```

may work... but you may have to declare an encoding type at the top of the file

Comment: Hope this helps someone..

I had this error...

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte ....
after reading an Excel File df = pd.read_excel... and trying to assign a new column to the dataframe like this df['new_col'] = 'foo bar'. Please read my answer in here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30765820/python-pandas-read-excel-returns-unicodedecodeerror-on-describe/43298880#43298880

Answer (score 0):

try this for unicode conversion:

`df=pd.read_excel(u"url/某物2008.xls", encoding='utf-8')`