# python pandas read_excel returns UnicodeDecodeError on describe()

Tags: python, excel, pandas, unicode

I love pandas, but I am having real problems with Unicode errors. read_excel() returns the dreaded Unicode error:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_excel('tmp.xlsx',encoding='utf-8')
df.describe()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
...
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 259: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I figured out that the original Excel had     (non-breaking space) at the end of many cells, probably to avoid conversion of long digit strings to float.

One way around this is to strip the cells, but there must be something better.

```
for col in df.columns:
    df[col]=df[col].str.strip()
```

I am using anaconda2.2.0 win64, with pandas 0.16

Comment: this worked for me once: df['somecol'].values.astype('unicode') 
https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7758

Comment: Do yourself a big favour and switch to python3 right away. Encoding problems are all solved in python3.

Answer (score 3):

Try this method suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26856793/pandas-read-excel-with-chinese-filename):

```
df=pd.read_excel('tmp.xlsx',encoding=sys.getfilesystemencoding())
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps someone.

I had this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte ....
```

after reading an Excel File `df = pd.read_excel...` and trying to assign a new column to the dataframe like this `df['new_col'] = 'foo bar'`

After closer inspection, I found the problem to be. There were some `'nan'` columns in the dataframe due to missing column headers. After dropping the 'nan' columns using the following code, everything else was ok.

```
df = df.dropna(axis=1,how='all')
```