# Atomically read from excel (for luigi workflow)

Tags: python, pandas, luigi

I'm trying to open an excel file in my Luigi workflow using `pandas.read_excel()` using the built in (atomic) luigi methods.

if `self.input()` is my luigi target of my excel document, I want to do something like:

`with self.input().open('r') as f:
   pandas.read_excel(f)`

or more generally:

`with open(filename) as f:
   pandas.read_excel(f)`

However, this gives me an error:
`*** UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 10: invalid continuation byte`

Disclaimer:

The excel file is from an external task, so I do not have control over what type of computer it is made on or whether or not it contains NAs or blank cells.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python pandas read\_excel returns UnicodeDecodeError on describe()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30765820/python-pandas-read-excel-returns-unicodedecodeerror-on-describe)

Comment: looks like your input file has a non decodable character. Try looking at the file on excel and clean it. Otherwise look at the link on the previous comment :)

Comment: running: `self.input().open('r') as f:
pd.read_excel(f, encoding = sys.getfilesystemencoding())` does not fix the issue

Comment: @Laura If the excel sheet was produced on a windows machine, it's not going to be in your file system's encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was that my self.input() (that points to the place where my excel file is saved) should have used format = Nop. My luigi target should return something like:

```
luigi.LocalTarget('excelfile.xlsx', format=luigi.format.Nop)
```

With this target definition, I can atomically read using:

```
with self.input().open() as f:
    df = pd.read_excel(f)
```

Comment: I would humbly suggest, for the sake of completeness, that you explain what is actually going on. In particular, the documentation doesn't even say what the `format` argument is supposed to be doing. https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/luigi.local_target.html?highlight=localtarget#luigi.local_target.LocalTarget