# 'utf-8' codec can't decode using pandas and reading xlsx

Tags: python, pandas, xlsx

I'm trying read a xlsx file in python with padas but i get this:

> 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc9 in position 6: invalid
>   continuation byte

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\nlsouza\Desktop\teste3.xlsx')
query = data['Final'].values.tolist()
```

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30765820/python-pandas-read-excel-returns-unicodedecodeerror-on-describe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably trying to read an excel file containing special characters (Russian Symbols ... ).

You should add a parameter to your read_excel :

```
df=pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\nlsouza\Desktop\teste3.xlsx',encoding='utf-8')
```

Hope it'll work for you